# Pushing a 1-D array onto a 2-D array in C

Tags: c, pointers, arrays, struct, structure

I am working on a queue data structure. The structure is:

```
struct queue
{
 char array[MAX_LENGTH][8];
 int back;
};
```

It is designed to store a list of MAX_LENGTH strings that are 7 chars long.
I wish to push a 1D array of 8 chars (well, 7 chars and \0, just like the array in the struct).

I have this push code:

```
void push (struct queue *q, char s[]){
 q->array[q->back] = s;
}
```

Which I figure might work, but apparently does not. In cl (.net's C/C++) compiler, I get the following error:

> 2.c(29) : error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value

gcc returns a similar error, on the same line (but I forget, and don't have access to gcc at the moment).

I'm fairly new to structs, and pointers so there's probably something very obvious I'm not doing. Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to treat `q->array` just as you would any other array. You can't just "push" it, you have to pass the location you want to put it in then copy each character (or use q->back as your location). Something like this perhaps:

```
void push (struct queue *q, char s[]){
  int i;
  for ( i = 0; s[i]; ++i ) 
    q->array[q->back][i] = s[i];
  q->array[q->back][i] = '\0'; 
}
```

Or use `strcpy`:

```
void push (struct queue *q, char s[]){
  strcpy(q->array[q->back], s);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Change it to:

```
void push (struct queue *q, char s[])
{
    strcpy(q->array[q->back], s);
}
```

You can assign structs in C using `=` but you can't assign arrays - you have to use strcpy/memcpy for things like this.

Comment: Maybe add some checking against buffer overflow?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a bounds-checked `strcpy` using only the standard C library functions, then `strncat` is actually your best bet:

```
void push (struct queue *q, char s[])
{
    q->array[q->back][0] = 0;
    strncat(q->array[q->back], s, sizeof q->array[q->back] - 1);
}
```

On the other hand, if you *know* for certain that `s` always points to an array of the same size as the array in the struct (as your question states), then `memcpy` is the simplest solution:

```
void push (struct queue *q, char s[])
{
    memcpy(q->array[q->back], s, sizeof q->array[q->back]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

strncpy(q->array[q->back], s,MAX_LENGTH) could be better to avoid buffer overflow

Comment: With strncpy(), you have to ensure null termination; it doesn't.  So you'd also need `q->array[q->back][7] = '\0';`.  We can discuss whether the last parameter to strncpy() should be 8 (safe enough) or 7 (since you're about to overwrite the 8th place...).